# Passing variables to a batch file from vbscript created by html form

Tags: html, vbscript, batch-file

I'm in the process of creating a web portal for bulk new user creation on both our AS400 and Domain, I've been able to get everything to work except for passing the variables from the HTML form to the batch files.

The batch files already existed and to keep this as simple as possible I decided to reuse them as this will be a strictly internal application.

I've declared my variables to be the input from the form and set them to be called by the vb script when running the batch file, however they are not being passed as the variables but as what is stated in the code.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong as I've not been able to find much information from searching the web on this problem?

If you need more information please let me know and I'll provide it.

```
<script language="VBScript">

strCode = textbox0.Value
strName = textbox1.Value
strIPMG = textbox2.Value
strServer = textbox3.Value

Sub isetup
dim shell
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
shell.run "N:\wwwroot\users\iSETUP01.bat strCode strName strIPGM strServer"
set shell=nothing

End Sub

Sub wsetup()
dim shell
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
shell.run "N:\wwwroot\users\wSETUP.bat strCode strIPGM"
set shell=nothing

End Sub

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need something like...

```
"N:\wwwroot\users\wSETUP.bat " & strCode & " " & strIPGM
```

Comment: Same for the previous one, which should be "N:\wwwroot\users\iSETUP01.bat " & strCode & " " & strName & " " & strIPGM & " " & strServer"

Comment: Thanks for the help Steve and Lizz, that looks like it helped but now the scripts are not running, I'll troubleshoot some more.

Comment: Make sure they run standalone first.  Then, if they don't work when launched by the shell, check security settings (the account it is running under).

Comment: Thanks Steve, I can get them to run in the shell, however when I try to use the web form the variables are not being set in the script. I've been looking for an answer to this problem, do you have an suggestions?

Comment: Where are they being lost, here? strCode = textbox0.Value   Is strCode set? BTW, textbox0?  Why not name it textboxCode? Ditto for the rest.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I realized I didn't have my form named and the script didn't know where to get the values for the variables. I fixed this issue and everything seems to be working now.